# How to reach "WAN SIDE" of my lan

Tags: nat, dmz

maybe this is a silly question and the answer is simple.

I set my router DMZ (zyxel router) to my dev server (Dns updated dynamically) and everything works good from outside my network.

From inside my LAN instead, the chosen domain name resolves in my router's ip, instead of my public dynamic ip, so that if I point the browser to my domain, I receive response from my router's web server (talking about port 80 to be honest.. because if I point to mysql serving on port 3306 no matter if I'm "in or out", it just works).

I expected to reach my server on https://my.domain.net/ and my router on http://192.168.X.X.

My server is simply an host of my lan (no separated vlan or so).

What am I missing? How should I solve this hassle?

thank u all

Comment: "dynamic public ip bound to domain name resolves to my router's ip". This sentence makes no sense. Dynamic public IP does not resolve to anything, it is just an IP address.

Comment: well.. actually it does: I explained my router WAN ip is dynamic. when the hosts inside my network make dns request to the domain I set in the dynamic dns service, that request resolves in the router's LOCAL IP instead of the server's, WAN, Demilitarized, IP

Comment: I don't think it is a good habit giving bad feedbacks to users as a punishment, even before being sure that the question has been understood, no matters who's the fault. There are billions of reasons causing misunderstandings, language in top of all of them. if this platform is intended to contribute to knowledge, well.. U'r not in the right mood

Comment: Anyway.. I changed the syntax of my question to try to avoid misunderstandings in future readers, and get, hopefully, some judgement-free help

Comment: What name server is used when the public domain name resolves to router's IP address?

Comment: to be more detailed, my lan is 192.168.X.X/24, my router is 192.168.X.251, my server is 192.168.X.174. 
My router's wan remote management is disabled, while it's lan management is on port 80. If I try to reach my server (174) from WAN  (ssh mydomain.com) I get it working, from inside my lan (same, ssh mydomain.com) I get response from my router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it seemed to be a router/modem related problem. After changing ISP (and consequently router) the problem doesn't show up anymore